Supported solution for Ubuntu Desktops in cloud native with Entra ID
Supporting Ubuntu Desktops in traditional Active Directory environments are working quite well using sssd, adsys and landscape.
But when it comes to an all cloud native environment using Entra ID, the traditional methods no longer works.
So, what is the supported way to get Ubuntu Desktops to work in such an environment? I've found this article
https://ubuntu.com/blog/azure-ad-authentication-comes-to-ubuntu-desktop-23-04
However this seems already deprecated. Then there is the authd project here,
https://github.com/ubuntu/authd but it's unclear if this is a supported tool, as it doens't appear to be included in Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
Also, ADsys don't work with Entra ID as there are no GPO's in Entra. What's the proposed way to manage clients then?
MS InTune is very limited when it comes to what it can do in Linux. Landscape might be an alternative if one uses the cloud version. But even landscape lacks in functionality.
Does anyone have any insights?
Thanks!

I don't think you can use Entra ID to manage Linux at this time.  This question is probably better suited for the Ubuntu discourse, etc. because only developers, etc. can answer this kind of question as to whether that integration is planned.
